# Map with two Key for a value?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, arraylist, linked-list

I want to create a map that has two key :

```
map.put (key1,key2,value1);// Insert into map
map.get(key1,key2); // return value1
```

i have looking into **multikeyMap** but i don't know how i will do it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you just want a key which is created from two values. You may well find that those two values should naturally be encapsulated into another type anyway - or you *could* create a `Key2<K1, K2>` type. (The naming here would allow for `Key3`, `Key4` etc. I wouldn't encourage you to go too far though.)

For something in between, you could create a private static class within the class where this is really *needed* (if it's only an internal implementation detail). If it's not a natural encapsulation (e.g. it's something like "name and population", which doesn't make sense outside this specific scenario) then it would be good in terms of keeping meaningful property names, but without exposing it publicly.

In any of these scenarios, you'll end up with a new type with two final variables which are initialized in the constructor, and which contribute to both `equals` and `hashCode`. For example:

```
public final class Key2<K1, K2> {
    private final K1 part1;
    private final K2 part2;

    public Key2(K1 part1, K2 part2) {
        this.part1 = part1;
        this.part2 = part2;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Key2)) {
            return false;
        }
        // Can't find out the type arguments, unfortunately
        Key2 rawOther = (Key2) other;
        // TODO: Handle nullity
        return part1.equals(rawOther.part1) &&
            part2.equals(rawOther.part2);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        // TODO: Handle nullity
        int hash = 23;
        hash = hash * 31 + part1.hashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + part2.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    // TODO: Consider overriding toString and providing accessors.
}
```

The more situation-specific types would be slightly simpler as they wouldn't be generic - in particular this would mean you wouldn't need to worry about the type arguments, and you could give the variables better names.

Answer (score 10):

How about

```
class Key{
 private final String key1;
 private final String key2;
//accessors + hashcode + equals()
}
```

and

```
Map<Key, Value> map
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using one of Guava's [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) implementations. From the documentation:

> A collection that associates an ordered pair of keys, called a row key
>   and a column key, with a single value. A table may be sparse, with
>   only a small fraction of row key / column key pairs possessing a
>   corresponding value.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use outside libraries, [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) provides exactly this as [`Table<R, C, V>`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table), referring to the two keys as "row" and "column" respectively.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not map key a String and concatinate key1+key2

Comment: In many cases that wouldn't work nicely. For example, if they're both integers then 1,11 ends up the same as 11,1 - unless you *also* start adding a separator, etc. There's no inherent call for a string representation as far as I can see - it would be cleaner to use separate fields in a new type.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to access via key1 and key2 together you could just concatenate them with a separator together as key and use a normal map.

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate that Java does not support tuples at language level, and therefore you have to go for ad hoc structures like the ones showed in some answers here. This leads to atrocious amount of boilerplate and code duplication.

[Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) has a library support for tuples. The class that fits the bill here is `P2`. The name means "product with 2 elements". (Product is just an algebraic term for composite types.) The library supports tuples of up to 8 elements. The `P{n}` classes override all the necessary methods

There is a class named `P` that provides a static factory method `p` for constructing tuples.

**Usage:**

```
import fj.P2;
import fj.Ord;
import fj.data.TreeMap;

import static fj.Ord.*;
import static fj.P.*;

TreeMap<P2<Integer, String>, String> m = 
  TreeMap.<P2<Integer, String>, String>empty(p2Ord(intOrd, stringOrd)).
  set(p(1, "2"), "onetwo").
  set(p(5, "3"), "fivethree");
```